# Problem in Finding the minimum value in array

Tags: vhdl

I’m trying to find the minimum value of an "array" which includes 19 values with VHDL. The 19 values are represented by `J0` to `J18` and used as input into my `Find_min_v3` module.
The structure below (in the picture) I use to compare 2 inputs and the output is stored in REG. The utilization of a myriad of the structures leads to the notification

> “[Netlist 29-101] Netlist 'MODULE' is not ideal for floorplanning, since the cellview 'MODULE' contains a large number of primitives.  Please consider enabling hierarchy in synthesis if you want to do floorplanning.”

I have 2 questions:

1.Why It contains many primitives leading to be not ideal for floorplanning

2.How can I optimize a myriad of the structures which connected in order to find the minimum value of array ? or Do you have other method to find minimum value ?

[image]

That's My code

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
entity Find_min_v3 is
    Port ( i_clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in STD_LOGIC;
           EN_RUNNING  : in STD_LOGIC;
           J0 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J1 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J2 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J3 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J4 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J5 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J6 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J7 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J8 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J9 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J10 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J11 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J12 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J13 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J14 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J15 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J16 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J17 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J18 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0);
           J_Min_out          : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0)
           );
end Find_min_v3;

architecture Behavioral of Find_min_v3 is
    TYPE    J_type        IS ARRAY (0 to 18) OF SIGNED(11 downto 0) ;
    SIGNAl  r_J           : J_type;
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage1_0    : SIGNED (11  downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage1_1    : SIGNED (11  downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage1_2    : SIGNED (11  downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage1_3    : SIGNED (11  downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage1_4    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage1_5    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage1_6    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage1_7    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage1_8    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage1_9    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);

    SIGNAl  out_min_stage2_0    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage2_1    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage2_2    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage2_3    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage2_4    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);

    SIGNAl  out_min_stage3_0    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage3_1    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage3_2    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);

    SIGNAl  out_min_stage4_0    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);
    SIGNAl  out_min_stage4_1    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);

    SIGNAl  out_min_stage5_0    : SIGNED (11 downto 0);


BEGIN
   r_J(0)   <= signed(J0) WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(1)   <= signed(J1) WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(2)   <=signed(J2)  WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(3)   <=signed(J3)  WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(4)   <=signed(J4)  WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(5)   <=signed(J5)  WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(6)   <=signed(J6)  WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(7)   <=signed(J7)  WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(8)   <=signed(J8)  WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(9)   <=signed(J9)  WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(10)  <=signed(J10) WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(11)  <=signed(J11) WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(12)  <=signed(J12) WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(13)  <=signed(J13) WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(14)  <=signed(J14) WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(15)  <=signed(J15) WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(16)  <=signed(J16) WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(17)  <=signed(J17) WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
   r_J(18)  <=signed(J18) WHEN EN_RUNNING ='1';
-------stage1
   STAGGE1_0: PROCESS (i_clk,reset)
   BEGIN
        IF (RISING_EDGE(i_clk)) THEN
            IF  (reset ='0') THEN
                    --out_ind_stage1_0 <= (others => '0');
                    out_min_stage1_0 <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage1_0    <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage1_1   <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage1_2   <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage1_3    <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage1_4   <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage1_5   <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage1_6   <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage1_7   <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage1_8   <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage1_9   <= (others => '0');

                      out_min_stage2_0   <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage2_1   <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage2_2   <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage2_3   <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage2_4   <= (others => '0');

                      out_min_stage3_0   <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage3_1   <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage3_2   <= (others => '0');

                      out_min_stage4_0   <= (others => '0');
                      out_min_stage4_1   <= (others => '0');

                      out_min_stage5_0   <= (others => '0');
            ELSE

                    IF (r_J(1)>r_J(0)) THEN
                        out_min_stage1_0 <= r_J(0);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage1_0 <= r_J(1);
                    END IF;

                    IF (r_J(3)>r_J(2)) THEN
                           out_min_stage1_1 <= r_J(2);
                    ELSE
                           out_min_stage1_1 <= r_J(3);
                    END IF;

                    IF (r_J(5)>r_J(4)) THEN
                        out_min_stage1_2 <= r_J(4);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage1_2 <= r_J(5);
                    END IF;

                    IF (r_J(7)>r_J(6)) THEN
                        out_min_stage1_3 <= r_J(6);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage1_3 <= r_J(7);
                    END IF;

                    IF (r_J(9)>r_J(8)) THEN
                        out_min_stage1_4 <= r_J(8);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage1_4 <= r_J(9);
                    END IF;

                    IF (r_J(11)>r_J(10)) THEN
                        out_min_stage1_5 <= r_J(10);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage1_5 <= r_J(11);
                    END IF;

                    IF (r_J(13)>r_J(12)) THEN
                        out_min_stage1_6 <= r_J(12);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage1_6 <= r_J(13);
                    END IF;

                    IF (r_J(15)>r_J(14)) THEN
                        out_min_stage1_7 <= r_J(14);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage1_7 <= (r_J(15));
                    END IF;

                    IF (r_J(17)>r_J(16)) THEN
                        out_min_stage1_8 <= r_J(16);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage1_8 <= r_J(17);
                    END IF;

                    out_min_stage1_9 <= r_J(18);

                    ---------
                    IF (out_min_stage1_0)> out_min_stage1_1 THEN
                        out_min_stage2_0 <= out_min_stage1_1;
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage2_0 <= out_min_stage1_0;
                    END IF;

                    IF (out_min_stage1_2)>(out_min_stage1_3) THEN
                        out_min_stage2_1 <= (out_min_stage1_3);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage2_1 <= (out_min_stage1_2);
                    END IF;

                    IF (out_min_stage1_4)>out_min_stage1_5 THEN
                        out_min_stage2_2 <= (out_min_stage1_5);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage2_2 <= (out_min_stage1_4);
                    END IF;

                    IF (out_min_stage1_6)>(out_min_stage1_7) THEN
                        out_min_stage2_3 <= (out_min_stage1_7);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage2_3 <= (out_min_stage1_6);
                    END IF;

                    IF (out_min_stage1_8)>out_min_stage1_9 THEN
                        out_min_stage2_4 <= (out_min_stage1_9);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage2_4 <= (out_min_stage1_8);
                    END IF;

                    ---------STAGE3
                    IF (out_min_stage2_0)>out_min_stage2_1 THEN
                        out_min_stage3_0 <= (out_min_stage2_1);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage3_0 <= (out_min_stage2_0);
                    END IF;

                    IF (out_min_stage2_2)>(out_min_stage2_3) THEN
                        out_min_stage3_1 <= (out_min_stage2_3);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage3_1 <= (out_min_stage2_2);
                    END IF;

                    out_min_stage3_2 <= (out_min_stage2_4);
                    -------------STAGE4

                    IF (out_min_stage3_1)>out_min_stage3_0 THEN
                        out_min_stage4_0 <= (out_min_stage3_0);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage4_0 <= (out_min_stage3_1);
                    END IF;

                    out_min_stage4_1 <= (out_min_stage3_2);

                    -------------STAGE5
                    IF (out_min_stage4_0)>(out_min_stage4_1)THEN
                        out_min_stage5_0 <= (out_min_stage4_1);
                    ELSE
                        out_min_stage5_0 <= (out_min_stage4_0);
                    END IF;

                    J_Min_out         <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(out_min_stage5_0);

                END IF;
            END IF;

   END PROCESS;

end Behavioral;
```

That's usage report
[image]

Comment: Can you share your source code and resources (e.g., lut and bram) usage report?

Comment: If your implementation is based on a sorting network to find the minimum, the needed resources are exploding on the number of inputs and the size of each input. A 64 input vector each of 64 bits can fill up the biggest currently available FPGAs! ou should look for a sequential or n-out-of-m inputs at a time solution to save resources.

Comment: @Paebbes. I see, but I add the module in The schematic so that the number of inputs and the size of each input regards as Signals,REG,.... in FPGA . I'll show the code below and really hope you help me

Comment: @delirium I'll share code below

Comment: Before anything else, you are indeed using more I/O resources than you have. As @Paebbels commented you should adapt your solution (e.g., serializing your inputs) to save resources.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are getting through synthesis but hitting this issue in place & route? It could be because of the number of IOs in the device you are using. (243 needed only 100 available).

Couple of other things looking at the code.

You don't need reset in your process sensitivity list.

I'm not sure why you need the conditional type casting. Why not type cast directly without looking at the running signal?

This implementation will take several clock cycles to compute the result. Hope that latency is acceptable in your application.